# redirecting to page in edit mode issue in salesforce1

Tags: apex, salesforce1-app

I have a class to redirect to  page in edit mode, it is working fine in desktop.
    but in mobile it is not redirecting the the pagerefrence which i have declared below.
    can you please let me know how to fix this?

```
public  PageReference  waitss(){
         delay.delaytime(10000);
         lead l=[SELECT Id, Name FROM lead WHERE CreatedDate = TODAY ORDER BY CreatedDate DESC LIMIT 1];

        return new PageReference('/'+l.id+'/e');

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use [sforce.one Object's Navigation method](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.salesforce1.meta/salesforce1/salesforce1_dev_jsapi_sforce_one.htm) for Salesforce1 which is based on JavaScript.

A typical function performing navigation for both Salesforce1 and web version would be as-

```
function actioninvoke(){
    if(typeof sforce !== 'undefined' && 
        sforce != null) {
        // perform navigation using Salesforce1 method
    }
    else {
        // call action function which calls apex method for redirection
    }
}
```

Comment: Can't we redirect it through apex?

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: How can i pass the input parameter as lead to javascript function from apex?

Comment: If you have additional questions, avoid asking them in comments. Instead, ask a [new question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/ask).